# genymotion: "player.exe sttoped working"

Tags: android, windows-7, genymotion

I installed the package of GENYMOTION for windows(7) from their official web. It installed me the Oracle VM VirtualBox and the Genymotion. After that I opened the VirtualBox and then the Genymotion and downloaded the Galaxy Nexus-4.3-API 18-720x1280 and some others (all with API 18).

Then I tried to run it but after a while appered a message saying: "player.exe stopped working". I've been a lot of time trying to make it work but I really don´t know how to fix it...

Here I leave a link to my logs:

genymotion.log-> http://www.javieravello.com/genymotion/

genymotion-player.log->  http://www.javieravello.com/genymotion-player/

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try to launch your VM from VirtualBox? Sometimes Virtualbox provide explicite error message that could help to solve the problem.

Comment: Idid it and this is what i've got: http://www.javieravello.com/img/asdf.png     
Any idea of what it's going wrong??

Answer (score 3):

I solved it!! As it says in their FAQ:

When you start a virtual device, you got an error about OpenGL initialization.
This is probably due to an outdated video driver, or a very old video chipset.
Try to update your graphic card driver using the latest version provided by your manufacturer (available on their website).

Comment: Thanks for elucitade it. I'm getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to know your video cards name and version.
In Windows you can learn by this way

```
Control Panel -> Display -> Change display settings -> Advanced settings
```

after that you search google for updated driver and install it.
I fix this problem by this way. 
My video card is Intel HD grapshic 3000 and I download [this](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=23764&lang=eng)

driver and fix my problem. I hope you will solve this problem.

Comment: `Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Display -> Change display settings -> Advanced settings` for those who "View by: Category"