# Genymotion player.exe has stopped but all drivers up to date

Tags: android, driver, genymotion

I am using the Genymotion application to emulate Android devices. Upon using it, the error seen below appears within 20 seconds of booting:

[image]

Now many suggest to simply update graphics car drivers ([genymotion player.exe stoped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727538/genymotion-player-exe-stoped-working) and [genymotion: "player.exe sttoped working"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613102/genymotion-player-exe-sttoped-working)) they are all up to date and I have enabled VT-x as seen here:

[image],

But the error persists

My computer is not that old as it's from 2010, an HP dv7 6b32us. How can I get Genymotion to run?

**Note:** This question is still open as the error still occurs even with 256 mb memory

Comment: Which device you try to emulate? -- Also, try: Before you launch the device open VirtualBox

Comment: I tried Samsung Galaxy S5. Do you mean run on virtual box?

Comment: Can we enter a chat?

Comment: I mean just launch VirtualBox application without doing anything else, then launch the device from the emulator

Comment: Found an issue, my computer is running out of memory...down to 4mb free when running Android studio and emulator, so it kills the emulator, I reduced the memory used to 256 mb so no problem now

Comment: Neglect the previous comment, still have issues...

Comment: Can you try to run the emulator without any other program?

Comment: Yes, it does run, very weird, I moved to 256 mb memory and it's fine like 50% of the time, otherwise the "player.exe" appears,

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by changing default vga for player.exe of genymotion to Intel integrated graphic processor hope this help someone

[image: Change default VGA Setting for player.exe of genymotion]

Comment: I do not have NVIDIA, I have Intel, how can I access the graphics properties?

Comment: if it is Intel Only you should upgrade your graphic driver these setting is only for computers that has two VGA with Optimus technology for Nvidia and AMD Dynamic Switchable Graphics for ATI VGAs

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Windows [Version 5.2.4630]
(C) Copyright 1985-2014 Microsoft Corp.

Windows Genymotion Error Player Exe Has Stopped Working may caused by some of the following errors

```
Windows Explorer Errors
Javascript Errors
Hardware Malfunction
```

Error Symptom include:
Can not printing file

```
Blue Screen
IO error
Shutdown problems
Http error
```

1) Modify The Application Data Path Inside The Registry

Click onto “Start Menu” – search for “Regedit.exe”
Browse to the following path in RegEdit:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Microsoft -> Windows -> CurrentVersion -> Explorer -> User Shell Folders
Double click the entry called “AppData”
Replace the original value with your own local profile path
Press OK
Restart your PC